# how to read digit start with 0 by Streamtokenizer in java

Tags: java

I try to read a time input like "0900" by using Streamtokenizer, but the output is always "900", is there any way to output the whole digit like "0900"? i try google a bit, but nothing really work...

```
for example 
if(f.ttype != StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER ){
    System.out.println("not a src time"); 
} else {
    int Dtime =(int) f.nval;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.format("%04d", theTime);` for a time of 4 digits.